# Desktop Browsers Not Working, but "Metro" Internet Explorer Works (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer, internet-connection

I'm trying to help my dad fix his computer after he inadvertently downloaded and installed a bundle of 15 spyware/malicious programs (which he has since uninstalled via the Control Panel).  However, Windows is unable to complete a system restore and Windows Defender isn't picking up on anything.

The only symptom seems to be that all browsers (IE 11, Chrome, Firefox) in "Desktop" mode are unable to connect to the Internet (displaying the classic "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage", etc.).  We know the internet connection does work because he is able to use Skype and the "Metro" version of Internet Explorer works fine.

We tried all the suggestions on the Microsoft website below, but none seemed to help (I initially thought it would be some kind of proxy issue but it doesn't seem to be).
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956196

I'm not very familiar with Windows 8 (my system runs 7) or dealing with spyware-related issues, so I was hoping one of you might have some tips.  I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realize that the virus/spyware might have infected the computer even after the removal of the stuff in the control panel.  Realize that you might be looking at doing a FULL restore from the last known good backup (hopefully you are smart enough to make these -- even on home systems).

Your final resort would be to reinstall from scratch to ensure all problems are taken care of and no residual of any virus/spyware is present.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Defender isn't updated as often as it should be. I would use Avast and see if this helps.

http://download.cnet.com/Avast-Free-Antivirus-2014/3000-2239_4-10019223.html